# How to store QR code data in Firebase after scanning

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, qr-code, zxing

I'm curently working on an application that has register/login form of a user and a shop, whenever a user is loged in with it's credentials the User Profile is being displayed and a QR code with it's data is being created.

Whenever a shop is logged in it can scan the User's QR code and show it's credentials, I'm trying to figure out how can I store user's credentials when scanned to a new path created on the **Firebase** to show in which shop the user has entered.

I'm thinking that somehow whenever the shop is scanning the QR code of the user, it is going to store the data to some strings and then a new "field" will be created in **Firebase**.

Also the library that I'm using for the **QR code** is the **Zxing library**.

Any ideas?

**EDIT, ANSWER FOUND**

This function takes the result from the QR code and stores it on Firebase

```
 public void resultSplitter(String result) {
    String keys[] = {"FullName", "Email", "Phone", "Age"};
    String splitted[] = result.split("\n");
    HashMap<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        splitted[i].trim();
        String value = splitted[i].split(keys[i] + " :")[1].trim();
        valuesMap.put(keys[i], value);
    }

    User record = new User(
            valuesMap.get("FullName"),
            valuesMap.get("Email"),
            valuesMap.get("Phone"),
            valuesMap.get("Age"),
            elseReader,
            timestamp.getTime());

    FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference("Reader")
            .child("Shops")
            .push()
            .setValue(record)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ElseRead.this, "Record added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(ElseRead.this, "Failed to record! Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

Comment: "Any ideas?" is not really a great type of question for Stack Overflow, as there are way too many possible answers. What is the problem you encountered when you tried to store the QR code as a string in Firebase? If you didn't try it yet, I recommend starting here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Well yes you are right, just started over in the community, I will keep that in mind. Well the QR code is not being stored anywhere, it is being generated when the User logs in to his profile.

Comment: Sure, but you want to store it in the database, right? So if you try that (with the link I provided above), does it work? If not, what is the concrete problem you encounter? Is there an error message?

Comment: I found something that works for me, I will post my code. I just wanted to get the scanned results from the QR code and store them in the database under specific paths. I didn't want to store the QR code in the database. Anyway next time I will provide code and I will try to explain my problem better. Thank you for your response!